# SMS Provider Android

Tags: android, sms, message, provider

I would handle sms with my app.

I use this code to insert the message into provider android:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", phoneNumber);
        values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put("body", text);
        values.put("type", 1);
        values.put("read", 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            values.put(Inbox.DATE_SENT, System.currentTimeMillis());
        context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

The message is insert correctly but when i see it i reply an error.

The date of receipt is correct, but the date of dispatch is not correct (it's set to 1 January 1970).

How can i set it?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `values.put("date_sent", System.currentTimeMillis());` instead of of using the API level check if you haven't already.